# get the root directory of a maven application

Tags: java

I need to provide a settings file for my program, to which the user should have access to write some of the settings i need.
I created a file under a new directory (called settings) on the root of my application, but i have problem finding it at run time.
I use
`File SettingsFile=new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()+"settings/CreateSettings.txt");`
When i execute this under eclipse i get
`/application/home/dir/target/classes/settings/ZipCreateSettings.txt` which is wrong.

If i execute it on terminal using java -jar, i get the correct path,
`/application/home/dir/settings/ZipCreateSettings.txt`

This would cause me problems cos i need to run the application directly from eclipse and not use the terminal, even though it is going to be executed using the jar when it is up and running.
I cant keep it like that anyway, cos this code might end up in someone else's hands, and they would have no idea what to do with it.

I have also used some other techniques like
`new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath();` but this always gives me the current working directory, so if i execute the jar from /home, i would get /home.

I think the problem might be maven (which i am not familiar with at all) since my code worked with a plain java application some time ago.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir");` Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: @McN no, this gets the current directory of the user, /home for example

Comment: You're thinking of `user.home`, `user.dir` is the current working directory. So you should be able to find the file as `System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//settings//CreateSettings.txt";`

Comment: no, i know and i tested it, user.dir gives me the current directory from where the user executed the application. at least under Linux, cant tell about Windows

Answer (score 0):

Since your file will be located outside your classpath, it is basically outside your application. Your application is not aware of files existing outside it's classpath. So you will need some kind of way to provide the Full/Absolute path to your file. You can't use the classloader in your case.

I suggest you use a system param instead of a hardcoded value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201349/how-to-read-properties-file-placed-outside-war)

Comment: cant i add it to the class path somehow?

Comment: Yes, either you move your file inside your classpath. Normally, main/resources is included in the classpath. Or you add the folder to your buildpath. In Eclipse Right-click on your project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Source -> Add folder.  Then, add an exclusuion pattern ** on your folder so that it knows your folder won't include .class files.