# Error when trying to read a .properties file outside java .war

Tags: java, tomcat

I am building a Java Web Application which lets users upload some files to the server. Since the .war file may be deployed in servers having different file system hierarchies, I want to provide a .properties file and let the server admin define the location to save these files during initial system configuration. My application would then read this .properties file to determine where to store the uploaded files.

While searching for a way to do this I came across a similar question on Stack Overflow and tried to follow the instructions give in the following answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941774

I wanted to try out if this solution would work.
So I edited my /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/context.xml file and included the following between the `<Context> </Context>` tags

```
<Environment name="config" value="/home/nilushan/temp/"  
     type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

I created a file named yourfile.properties in /home/nilushan/temp and also copied the given Java code and executed it.

However I kept getting "exception in jndi lookup" message. After changing the code to print the exception, this is what I get
"exception in jndi lookup:javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [config] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [config]."

From the error message I understand that this has something to do with not being able to read what is in the context.xml file and nothing to do with yourfile.properties file.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong to get this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try to remove the leading `/` in front of home. In your found answer, the given path starts at root (`C:\...`), so it's absolute. But obviously you use a relative path which starts at the folder `home`.

Comment: @IQV, I removed the leading / infront of home as suggested and checked. However the outcome didn't change

Answer (score 0):

Well a good solution to the problem is using config server. When you set it up you can direct your properties file to take it's configuration from it. It is quite easy to set up, here is a link to the documentation(it's quite short so you should understand it very fast) [link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html). You can also use it for other war/jar files.